# Eloquent groupBy make "SQLSTATE[42000]" with valid SQL query in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a strange problem with Eloquent which I'm trying to do the following:

```
$this->node = \DB::table('permission')
                ->select('permission.id',
                         'object.name as object_name',
                         'permission.created_at',
                         'object.id as object_id')
                ->join('object', 'object.id', '=', 'permission.object_id')
                ->join('action', 'action.id', '=', 'permission.action_id')
                ->where('permission.person_id', $this->person['id'])
                ->groupBy('permission.object_id')
                ->orderBy('permission.created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(5);
```

**Laravel Framework** report an Error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 761: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1055 'permission.id' isn't in GROUP
>   BY (SQL: select `permission`.`id`, `object`.`name` as `object_name`,
>   `permission`.`created_at`, `object`.`id` as `object_id` from
>   `permission` inner join `object` on `object`.`id` =
>   `permission`.`object_id` inner join `action` on `action`.`id` =
>   `permission`.`action_id` where `permission`.`person_id` = 1 group by
>   `permission`.`object_id` order by `permission`.`created_at` desc limit
>   5 offset 0)

I've added an Eloquent debugging function **DB::listen** in *AppServiceProvider*:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
         DB::listen(function ($query) {

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($query->sql);
            echo "</pre>";

            // $query->sql
            // $query->bindings
            // $query->time
        });
    }
    ...
```

And it does print this SQL query:

```
select  `permission`.`id`, 
        `object`.`name` as `object_name`, 
        `permission`.`created_at`, 
        `object`.`id` as `object_id` 
from `permission` 
inner join `object` on `object`.`id` = `permission`.`object_id` 
inner join `action` on `action`.`id` = `permission`.`action_id` 
where `permission`.`person_id` = 1 
group by `permission`.`object_id` 
order by `permission`.`created_at` desc 
limit 5 offset 0
```

Which is valid in *MySQL* through **PhpMyAdmin** and here is the output for the query:
[image: SQL Query Output]
Even So, I tested in `mysql` command directly and it does work just fine, look at *mysql output*:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does it do a count and then execute the real query? The quoted exception has a query in it that isn't a count.

Comment: Laravel 5.3 features a `'strict' => true` in `config/database.php` which turns on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Comment: No, it just stopped at counting. But when I removed **groupBy** it does count and then made the query!

Comment: @mazedlx I turn `strict option` from false into true and I made a clean cache for everything by **artisan command**, but still the same problem appears.

Comment: @Shadow it was **off by default** and I turned **on** according to *mazedlx*, but no difference at all same error still exists.

Comment: No, @mazedlx did not suggest to turn this setting on.

Comment: Unfortunately, either way didn't help the issue.

Comment: Oh boy, what the heck? Guys I made a mistake which I did focus on a query not made a problem at all !!! Now I reformed my question and change images focus on the error itself, sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Faced same problem with laravel 5.3
They are trying to enforce strict query writing came with `mysql-5.7`

However to disabled this just go to `config/database.php` and change `strict` flag

```
'mysql' => [
            .
            .
            .
            'strict' => false,
            //'strict' => true,
            .
            .
        ],
```

Hope this will solve your problem too.

PS - For details on strict query writing refer to @Shadow's answer

Answer (score 8):

This query is against the sql standard and is only valid in mysql under certain sql mode settings. See mysql documentation on [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list,
>   HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that
>   are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally
>   dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns. For example,
>   this query is illegal in standard SQL92 because the nonaggregated name
>   column in the select list does not appear in the GROUP BY:
>
> SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)   FROM orders AS o, customers
>   AS c   WHERE o.custid = c.custid   GROUP BY o.custid; For the query to
>   be legal in SQL92, the name column must be omitted from the select
>   list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301
>   if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a
>   relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This
>   would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of
>   customers.

You either need to disable the only_full_group_by sql mode (it is part of strict sql mode as well), or use [any_value()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) function in the select list for non-aggregated fields that are not in the group by clause.

> ```
> SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
> ```

Comment: I have test SQL query in *mysql* directly and it doesn't compliant. I did update my question with *mysql output*.

Comment: Your test query differs from the query that reports the error message. You are comparing apples with pears.

Comment: Ah,  indeed ... you're right!
I think I need to dig more inside **Laravel Framework** itself, it looks like *DB::listen* didn't report all SQL queries.
I will update my question if I found the main **Bug** in **Eloquent Library**.

Comment: The query you tested is probably used by eloquent do determine the size of the resultset, but it is not the same query that produces the error message. In your query there is no count() used. I do not even understand why you use group by in that query in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is.
I used **groupBy** in this query because I want to show the current existing permissions for all objects from `permission` table in the Frontend, every `object` has many permissions.

Comment: If you want to retrieve all permissions, then you either should not group by on the object_id and use php to generate the results, or you can use group_concat() function to get multiple values in a delimited string by group. Nevertheless, the error is caused by the settings I described in the answer.

Comment: The problem isn't in SQL query, it is in **Eloquent Library** in **Laravel Framework**

Comment: Based on the above I do not think you arecright, but it is your code...