# Laravel Sql syntax error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

This is my Laravel query:

```
$items =  DashboardItem::distinct()->where('dashboard_id',$dashboard->id)->groupBy('type')->get();
```

I got a `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055` error in this query.

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'testapp.dashboard_items.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select distinct * from `dashboard_items` where `dashboard_id` = 3 group by `type`)
```

Sql Query:

```
select distinct * from `dashboard_items` where `dashboard_id` = 3 group by `type`
```

But when running this sql query in PHPMyAdmin I got the result

Comment: @Punit.... same error

Comment: convert your query builder to sql string `echo DashboardItem::distinct()->where('dashboard_id',$dashboard->id)->groupBy('type')->toSql();` to investigate it

Comment: dashboard_id is primary key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138090/eloquent-groupby-make-sqlstate42000-with-valid-sql-query-in-laravel-5-3?rq=1 Found the solution in this post.

Comment: I see................

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$items =  DB::table('dashboard_items')->where('dashboard_id',$dashboard->id)->groupBy('type')->distinct()->get();
```