# Refresh laravel setting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the same issue as this guy had in here [Eloquent groupBy make "SQLSTATE[42000]" with valid SQL query in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39138090/5871514)

I am using laravel on a shared hosting environment. The accepted answer asks to remove the sql strict mode in the `config/database.php`. I did the same but the setting doesnot takes place.

How do you refresh your settings in laravel to make them into effect?

Am i doing something wrong here?

> Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'foodq7y4_test_db.posts.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `posts`.*, `blog_users`.`name`, `post_tag`.`tag_id`, `post_tag`.`post_id`, `tags`.`name`, `categories`.`name` from `posts` inner join `categories` on `posts`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` inner join `blog_users` on `blog_users`.`id` = `posts`.`author_id` inner join `post_tag` on `posts`.`id` = `post_tag`.`post_id` inner join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` where (`posts`.`title` LIKE long post or `categories`.`name` LIKE long post or `tags`.`name` LIKE long post) group by `posts`.`id` limit 5 offset 0)' in /home/myuser/blogapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:770

This was my error that i received in my log.

**Update:**
I tried changing my environment as well as `app debug` to true.I dont think it  changed anything whereas it should have show me errors on the page , rather than in my log files.

I used laravel helper function , `config` to determine what my app debug is set to , it says false but i have changed it in my config file.

Why does it say so ?

```
config('app.debug');  // return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , laravel tends to cache your configuration so that it loads faster.

Just remove the config cache and everything is good to go.

`php artisan config:clear`

This worked for me , hope it helps.

**Just a side note :**

You cant stop laravel from making caches, it is more of an automatic thing however,you can clear your config after you make some changes to it.