# Get log in / log out time

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason, when I put my raw MYSQL into PHPMYADMIN it works the way I expect it to. However, when I use Laravel (I cant see why it's not working!) will give `Syntax error or access violation` error

Any help would be appreciated.

**Laravel**

```
$timings = DB::table('timings')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->selectRaw("employee_id, min(time_logged) AS minTime, max(time_logged) AS maxTime")
                    ->where('timings.employee_id' , $id)
                    ->groupBy('timings.employee_id', 'cast(time_logged AS date)' )
                    ->get();
```

**Raw MYSQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id, min(time_logged) AS minTime, max(time_logged) AS maxTime  
FROM timings 
WHERE timings.employee_id = 1
GROUP BY timings.employee_id, cast(time_logged AS date)
```

Comment: Try with `DB::raw('raw_phpmyadmin_full_query_here');` Be careful with sql injections because this way nothing is being checked. But test it to see if it is working at all. [Docs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2784-L2793).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138090/eloquent-groupby-make-sqlstate42000-with-valid-sql-query-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, make sure your credentials to access your database are correct(in your `.env` file.)
- Second, you will need to use [DB::raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) for expressions that operate on column name itself.

So your query would look like:

```
$timings = DB::table('timings')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->selectRaw("employee_id, min(time_logged) AS minTime, max(time_logged) AS maxTime")
                    ->where('timings.employee_id' , $id)
                    ->groupBy('timings.employee_id', DB::raw('cast(time_logged AS date)'))
                    ->get();
```

Comment: it was the DB::raw() in the groupBy which I needed. My database in my `.env` file was already correct

Comment: @NazarAbubaker Fair enough. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Although, can't say this is not recommended way but it's definitely not Laravel-style.

Let's assume you have `App\User`, and and `App\Timing`. Why don't you connect them using `hasOne`, so, your table for timings looks like this:

`| login_time | logout_time | user_id |
|------------|-------------|---------|
| xx-xx PM   | xx-xx PM    | 1       |
| xx-xx PM   | xx-xx AM    | 2       |`

Now you can easily make it, `$user->timings->login_time` :)

Why are people afraid of relationships, you should use it anytime possible.